# How can you select a worksheet in Excel with reference to a cell with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty new to VBA, so sorry if this is a basic question. In principle, I want to be able to select a worksheet, based on the contents of another cell. For example, if I want to select a tab called "1" (without the speech marks), can I select this tab by using, say, cell C5 which contains the number 1?

As a guess, I tried Worksheets(Range("C5")).Select, but this didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `Worksheets(CStr(Range("C5").Value)).Select`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the numeric value to string. I also might recommend:

- Making sure the sheet isn't hidden.
- Using Double click instead.

This code will work, or [see this spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g6g63ub-voTbR1IW8A?e=KwYem4).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    'double click option
    If Target.Address = Me.Range("C5").Address Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CStr(Target.Value))
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Activate
     End With
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Me.Range("C5").Address Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CStr(Target.Value))
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Activate
     End With
    End If

End Sub
```